# PWM Motor speed control using PIC; What mosfet to use

Tags: pic, mosfet, pwm, dc-motor

I have a 5V PIC16f877a controlling the speed of the motor 12V which has a power rating of 8W; the current will be around(600mA) am I correct?

The motor is basically a small water pump commonly used in aquariums.
After much research; I still don't know what is the best MOSFET to use.
As I saw some of the answers use logic-level MOSFETs?
I have IRFZ46N and IRFZ22 in my hand; is the two transistor suitable and enough? or is there any other IR transistor is more suitable. i think IR will be much more available in my country.
Will the 12V 1000mA power supply I have enough?

Comment: If the MOSFETs are in your hand, be careful with the pins, or you could ruin them by ESD. :-)

Comment: Could you please add links to the relevant datasheets to your question? Also, please remove the last -nearly useless- sentence.

Comment: You mention "my country", but didn't fill in any location in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual part for this application would be the IRLML2502.  It can easily handle the current, has nicely low Rdson with 5 V drive, and is good to 20 V.

Don't forget the reverse Schottky diode accross the motor or you'll blow out whatever trasistor you use after the first few times it tries to turn off the motor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare two MOSFETs, a \$Q_{g}\cdot{}R_{ds(on)}\$ figure of merit is typically used. This will give you a rough idea of how good a MOSFET is for switching application. You will get both \$Q_{g}\$ and \$R_{ds(on)}\$ in the datasheets.